# MATLAB. Modify matrix rows starting by a certain (variable) colums index

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, indexing

I have a big matrix of numerical data, let assume here for practicity a small matrix

```
a=[1 1 1;
   1 1 1]
```

Then I have a vector of indices

```
b=[4;
   2]
```

My goal is to "apply" vector `b` to `a`, row by row, in such a way to nullify all the items of the i-th row of `a` which are falling in the columns whose indices are greater than the i-th element of `b`, when possible.

Therefore my desired output would be:

```
c=some_smart_indexing_operation(a,b) %this is pseudo-code of course
c=[1 1 1;
   1 0 0]
```

Let me comment the results row by row:

- on the first row, `b`'s first element is 4: having `a` only 3 colums no element is nullify
- on the second tow,  `b`'s second element is 2: I should nullify the second and the third element of this row.

I could perform such an operation with a `for` loop by I was wondering if I could get the same result applying some smart indexing operation or applying some vectorial native functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create a mask of zero-one values, and then multiply `a` element-wise by that mask:

```
c = a .* bsxfun(@lt, 1:size(a,2), b);
```

In Matlab R2016b onwards the following simpler syntax can be used:

```
c = a .* ((1:size(a,2))<b);
```

---

Another approach is to use the complementary mask to the one above as a [logical index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to write the zeros.

```
c = a;
c(bsxfun(@ge, 1:size(a,2), b)) = 0; % or c(((1:size(a,2))>=b)) = 0
```

Comment: This looks very smart. Can you please explain how `bsxfun` creates the mask? Thank you

Comment: @Marco It's just singleton expansion. [This link](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) explains what that is, both with `bsxfun` and with the newer, simpler syntax